# Error when running airflow webserver on WSL Ubuntu

Tags: airflow, windows-subsystem-for-linux, airflow-webserver

I am new to airflow, I have installed Ubuntu and enabled WSL version 1 on my windows 10 machine, I then made sure I had python 3.10.6 on the Ubuntu instance, and I installed pip, after that I installed apache-airflow 2.4.3
everything seemed to be fine, I used `aiflow db init`, and created an admin username, however, when I tried to access the webserver with this command `airflow webserver -p 8080` nothing loads in my localhost, so I thought a process has priority on 8080, I changed the port in airflow.cfg file and it worked fine, I tried the same command with the new port,  the webserver loaded and I was able to login [image: airflow starts fine]

However I am greeted with infinite errors and an unresponsive DAGs page, I can't click on anything in the DAGs page, and the terminal is full of errors as below, most of them show this error, ***`sqlite3.OperationalError: disk I/O error`***

[image]

[image]

[image: screenshot of airflow directory in root]

another issue, which I think is related, but I wanted to be sure, I tried closing and killing the process, and tried a different command `airflow webserver -D` and `airflow scheduler -D` they both run successfully and I saw the airflow process start messages, no errors showed up, however when I accessed the port the message told me the webserver was listening at, the page didn't even load and I got a This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect. error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by updating WSL from 1 to WSL 2, removing Ubuntu and installing it again from Windows App Store and basically doing all the same steps again. and it worked.